# SVG animateTransform tag is lost when using SVG use

Tags: html, svg

I've defined a spinning rectangle in an SVG file using symbols. The file is called my.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="100">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="hey">
            <rect x="150" y="20" width="60" height="60" fill="blue">
                <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 180 50" to="360 180 50" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I include this using svg use in my html file.

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="my.svg#hey"></use>
</svg>
```

What happens is, the `animateTransform` element is gone, and the rectangle does not spin.

I've verified this on many browsers and server types. I don't understand why it is dropped. I can literally copy-paste the `animateTransform` back in to the `svg use` element so it's not as if it is not supported - it is simply removed for some reason when called via `use`.

I've found out this is not the case when locally defined as per my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/27jozv8L/

How can I keep that `animateTransform` element when i use `svg use`?

---

In firefox the whole thing rotates, in chrome nothing happens.

Answer (score -3):

trouble with Chrome still now???
**I Updates my answer**: (TY to @ccprog)
 SMIL works in this moment with browsers FF & GC & Safari.. but don't work with IE&Edge
 and [Not currently planned](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/svgsmilanimation/?filter=f3e0000bf&search=smil).(https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil) 
My example below use CSS, works with Edge too 
 And about your code.. may be local troubles with Chrome? if don't works
Check `Flag to disable SMIL support`(see below)

for example on CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>.</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <style>
    .loader {
      position: relative;
      top: 20px;
      left: 150px;
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      background-color: #00f;
      -webkit-animation: spin 1200ms infinite linear;
      -moz-animation: spin 1200ms infinite linear;
      animation: spin 1200ms infinite linear;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes spin {
      from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

<del>Google has decided to no longer support the markup language in its Chrome browser. Those that open an SVG graphic with SMIL animation on Chrome 45 will see a screen that says that SMIL is deprecated and that you should switch to CSS or web animations.</del> 
`(Aug 18 2016 Google Removed SMIL deprecation warning)`

> Wed Jun 10 04:13:40 2015 UTC
>  
>   https://codereview.chromium.org/1158563006
>   **Add SMIL deprecation warning**
>   Mon Jul 27 07:51:01 2015 UTC
>  
>   https://codereview.chromium.org/1251983005
>   **Flag to disable SMIL support**
>   Authors can use the command line flag --disable-blink-features=smil to
>   disable SMIL functionality.
>   Thu Aug 18 16:58:09 2016
>   https://codereview.chromium.org/2256013003
>   **Remove SMIL deprecation warning**

Monday, July 27, 2015
 
https://blog.chromium.org/2015/07/chrome-45-beta-new-es2015-features.html
In Chrome 45 (45.0.2454.85) there is a deprecation warning According to the warning:
`SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. 
Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.`

Test of browser for support SMIL(https://modernizr.com/download#setclasses&q=SVG+SMIL+animation)
A Guide to Alternatives
https://css-tricks.com/smil-is-dead-long-live-smil-a-guide-to-alternatives-to-smil-features/

For future projects, other animation options and libraries such as [SVG.js](http://svgjs.com/) or [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) or [D3](https://d3js.org/)  or [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) can be used.

... or use [ECMAScript(JS)](http://www.ecma-international.org/).

[SVG Animation in IE9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193979(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft

Comment: That deprecation notice by Google from 2015 has been taken back in [2016](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM/YGEJBsjUAwAJ). Chrome still supports SMIL, and there is no notice showing anywhere that it would not.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, Yes, support  ... but still not recomended status.. quot: "We firmly believe that SMIL is not in the best long-term interests of the open web platform"  (in this moment works in Chrome 62.0.3202.75; don't works in MS Edge 40.15063.674.0) [others browsers there](https://caniuse.com/#search=SMIL) and info from [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG/Animation) quot: "SMIL animation has been removed from SVG 2, and will not be added back." ((...  may be it is mistake. to be continued